# Asymptotic solution of an equation containing an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

The equation
$$\frac{2}{\pi  a} \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \exp \left(-\frac{\left(\cos (\theta ) \left(\pi  a^2 b^2-2 x\right)-\pi  a^2 b^2 \sec (\theta )\right)^2}{4 \pi  a^2 b^2}\right) \, d\theta=1$$

```
2/(Pi a) Integrate[Exp[-((Cos[\[Theta]] (\[Pi] a^2 b^2 -2 x) - 
\[Pi] a^2 b^2 Sec[\[Theta]])^2/(4 \[Pi] a^2 b^2))], {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}] = 1
```

defines, at least theoretically, $x$ as a function of $a$ and $b$, $x=f(a,b)$. All values are supposed to be real. Is it possible to find the asymptotic form of $x=f(a,b)$ in the limit of

1. $a\to 0$ and $b\to 0$;
2. $a\to 1$ and $b\to 0$.

I tried the followings for the first case ($a\to 0$ and $b\to 0$).
Substitute the integrand function with its Taylor series about $a= 0$ and $b=0$, thus the equation becomes:$$\frac{2}{\pi  a} \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \exp \left(x \left(\cos ^2(\theta )-1\right)-\frac{x^2 \cos ^2(\theta )}{\pi  a^2 b^2}\right) \, d\theta = 1$$
Solve the integral using the modified Bessel function $I_0$
$$\frac{2}{\pi  a} \frac{1}{2} \pi  e^{-\frac{1}{2} x \left(\frac{x}{\pi  a^2 b^2}+1\right)} I_0\left(\frac{1}{2} x \left(\frac{x}{a^2 b^2 \pi }-1\right)\right)=1$$
In the limit of $a\to 0$ and $b\to 0$
$$\frac{x}{\pi  a^2 b^2}+1=\frac{x}{\pi  a^2 b^2}-1\to \frac{x}{\pi  a^2 b^2}$$ then last equation becomes
$$\frac{1}{a} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\pi  a^2 b^2\right)}} I_0\left(\frac{x^2}{2 \left(a^2 b^2 \pi \right)}\right)=1$$
which becomes using the asymptotic form for for $I_0$ for large real z
$$I_0(z)=\frac{\exp (z)}{\sqrt{2 \pi  z}}$$
$$\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\pi  a^2 b^2\right)}} e^{\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\pi  a^2 b^2\right)}}}{a \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  x^2}{2 \left(\pi  a^2 b^2\right)}}}=1$$
Simplifying:
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2 b^2}}=\frac{1}{a}$$
which has solution
$$x=\pm b$$
Is it correct this reasoning? Any help for the second case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $\frac 12 \pi a^2b^2$ and not $k$ instead ?

Comment: Thank you @Claude Leibovici, I do not know if I can join $a$ and $b$ considering that the RHS is equal to $\frac{\pi  a}{2}$.

Comment: Since you have $a$ and $b$ $\to 0$, let $a=b$; it does not matter. By the way, you can simplify the argument of the exponential as $-\frac{((x-k) \cos (t)+k \sec (t))^2}{2 k}$. It does not help but ... it is shorter.

Comment: What is the context of this problem ? Is it an assignment ? Just curious. Cheers

Comment: The solution is the intercept with x-axis of an isotherm for a temperature field produced by a heat source on a semi-infinite solid.

Comment: If you use $k=\frac 12 \pi a^4$, the rhs would become $\sqrt[4]{ \frac{\pi ^3 k}{8}}$

Comment: The solution should be $x=\pm b$.